# can't configure socket.io with Google Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, socket.io, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make a simple chat app in which people will just send the message to everyone.
but I am not able to make it

These pictures will say you everything that I am doing.
Please correct me where I am wrong.

[image: Browser Console Error]

[image: Firbase Cloud Function LOG]

[image: MY CODE]

Comment: The first thing you are doing wrong is including screenshots in your question. Please include code and structures as text. Be specific about the issue and don't make us guess. See [No Screenshots](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and also take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Update your question and we'l take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From node.js back-end code, start listening to the requests by -

```
server.listen(...);
```

And make sure that the server and the client ports are same(or port forwarding is there if different.).
And if using TCP protocol then that port should be open.